# accessing sharepoint 2010 foundation via mobile

Tags: mobile

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site on our intranet . is it possible to let broswer enabled smart phone to access my Sharepoint non-internet facing site . 
so far I have [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2010/03/09/configure-sharepoint-server-2010-for-mobile-device-access.aspx).

am i going in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a non-internet facing site, your choices are limited.  As the article mentions, you could use Microsoft's UAG (f.k.a. ISA) to gain access.  I have accessed one this way before.  The other option is to connect to your intranet via VPN. Some smart phones have VPN clients built in.  Some VPN concentrators also allow web access (where you browse to a web page and a Java Applet or ActiveX VPN client is downloaded to the browser), but you will have to be sure your phone's browser works with Applets or ActiveX for this to work.

In summary, it boils down to two things:

1) You need a way to connect to your network

2) You need to be sure your phone and its browser supports the method you use to connect to your network

Comment: I guess I should also mention that if your phone is WiFi-enabled, then you can connect that way as well if you are on-premise and have wireless access on your network.